# On render in Html2Canvas, the page is scrolled to the top

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, html2canvas

I am using the html2canvas library, using the following code:

```
html2canvas(document.body, {
   onrendered: function(canvas) {
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
   }
});
```

When `onrendered` is fired, the page is automatically scrolled to the top. Is there anyway we can maintain our scroll position and not be automatically taken to the top of the page?

Comment: looks like the same thing happens on the demo page here: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html are you able to store the scrolltop before calling html2canvas and setting it back in the onrendered handler?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I took a look into the html2canvas.js and saw the following line:

```
_html2canvas.Parse = function (images, options) {
    window.scroll(0,0);
```

After commenting `window.scroll(0,0)` out, it worked fine for me on my local testing. Seems like that behaviour was intended by the author.

Of course you could also save your current scroll position into a variable when firing the code. The way you may do it depends on how you execute html2canvas. If it's a button like on the demo page, you would add an event listener to that button:

```
var scrollPos;
document.querySelector("screenshotButton").addEventListener("click",function() {
    scrollPos = document.body.scrollTop;
    html2canvas(document.body, {
       onrendered: function(canvas) {
          document.body.appendChild(canvas);
          window.scrollTo(0,scrollPos);
       }
    });
 });
```

Comment: That's fantastic, I spotted that line also just after I posted my bounty. It's all yours as soon as I can reward it :). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Comment: `onrendered` no longer exists. Use `onclone` instead, as shown at https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/configuration

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to adjust the scrollY position, relative to the current pageYOffset, try this

```
html2canvas(document.body, { scrollY: (window.pageYOffset * -1) })
```